# Logic in disabling/enabling buttons

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a number guesser game that I am trying to implement. When my input field, noted by the id "input" is blank...my clear button should be disabled but my implementations of it does not seem to be working, any advice?

```js
var actualNum = randomNumber();

function randomNumber(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
}

function findCorrectGuess(actualNum,userGuess){
  actualNum = parseInt(actualNum);
  userGuess = parseInt(userGuess);
  if(userGuess <= 0 || userGuess > 100){
    return "Error: Enter a number between 1 and 100"
  } else if(isNaN(userGuess)){
    return "Error: Insert an actual number."
  } else if(userGuess > actualNum){
    return "That is too high!"
  } else if (userGuess < actualNum){
    return "That is too low!"
  } else if (userGuess === actualNum){
    return "BOOM!"
  }
}

function reset(){
  actualNum = randomNumber();
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
  el = document.getElementById('player-guess')
  el.removeChild(el.firstChild)
}

function clearField(){
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
}

function guessToUI(){
  let userGuess = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('player-guess').innerHTML = `<center><h1>Your last guess was</h1><h2>${userGuess}</h2><h3>${findCorrectGuess(actualNum,userGuess)}</h3></center>`
}

// function disable(){
//   let guessInput = document.getElementById('guesser').value;
//   if(guessInput === ''){
//     document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
//   } else {
//     document.getElementById('clear').disabled = false;
//   }
// }


function listeners(){
  let = guessInput = document.getElementById('guesser').value;
  if(guessInput == ''){
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
  }
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('guesser').addEventListener('click', guessToUI);
    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clearField);
    document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
}

listeners();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <header>
      <h1><center><span id="num">Number</span> <span id="guess">Guesser</span></center></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="center-block">
        <input id="input" type="number" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your guess"><br>
        <button id="guesser" class="btn">Guess</button>
        <button id ="clear" class="btn">Clear</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="player-guess">

    </div>

    <footer class="bottom">
      <button id='reset' class="btn">Reset</button>
    </footer>

    <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could someone please explain the logic of implementing this? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: You're missing a `<form>`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code snippet. You just needed to add this line: `document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', disable);`. This basically executes the function `disable` every time the input changes.

Also I suggest you make a variable with `let input = document.getElementById('input')` for all of your repeating values, so that you can easily access it.

**Note:** You had a few more errors that I fixed.

```js
var actualNum = randomNumber();

function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
}

function findCorrectGuess(actualNum, userGuess) {
  actualNum = parseInt(actualNum);
  userGuess = parseInt(userGuess);
  if (userGuess <= 0 || userGuess > 100) {
    return "Error: Enter a number between 1 and 100"
  } else if (isNaN(userGuess)) {
    return "Error: Insert an actual number."
  } else if (userGuess > actualNum) {
    return "That is too high!"
  } else if (userGuess < actualNum) {
    return "That is too low!"
  } else if (userGuess === actualNum) {
    return "BOOM!"
  }
}

function reset() {
  actualNum = randomNumber();
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
  el = document.getElementById('player-guess')
  el.removeChild(el.firstChild)
}

function clearField() {
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
}

function guessToUI() {
  let userGuess = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('player-guess').innerHTML = `<center><h1>Your last guess was</h1><h2>${userGuess}</h2><h3>${findCorrectGuess(actualNum,userGuess)}</h3></center>`
}

function disable() {
  let guessInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (guessInput === '') {
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = false;
  }
}


function listeners() {
  let = guessInput = document.getElementById('guesser').value;
  document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('guesser').addEventListener('click', guessToUI);
  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clearField);
  document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', disable);

listeners();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
  <header>
    <h1>
      <center><span id="num">Number</span> <span id="guess">Guesser</span></center>
    </h1>
  </header>
  <div class="center-block">
    <form>
      <input id="input" type="number" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your guess"><br>
      <button id="guesser" class="btn">Guess</button>
      <button id="clear" class="btn">Clear</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="player-guess">

  </div>

  <footer class="bottom">
    <button id='reset' class="btn">Reset</button>
  </footer>

  <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an 'onkeyup' event for you input.

```
<input id="input" type="number" name="fname" onkeyup="inputChange()" placeholder="Enter your guess">
```

function for onkeyup

```
function inputChange()
{    
    if(document.getElementById('input').value != '')
    {
        document.getElementById('clear').disabled =false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Also add disable clear code on clear click function

```
function clearField(){
    document.getElementById('input').value = "";
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
}
```

By this when ever your input field is empty the clear button disabled property will be true. Hope this help